# Question was intended for Community Wiki

Tags: support, questions

My question was supposed to be a CW but because I tried to submit without a tag I didn't realise it reset the check-box for CW:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342635/why-do-people-insist-that-they-dont-need-to-follow-any-standards-closed

Also, is it really 'that' off the mark for a software Q&A?

Comment: You can turn your questions to CW after posting them also. Your question does not have a definite answer, it's argumentative, i.e. SO is not the correct place to post it.

Comment: There are tons of questions without specific answers, and I agree it should be closed if it 'gets' argumentative, but personally I feel it touches on an extremely difficult area in SD.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the "edit" link (under the tags) and check the CW box after the post has been submitted.

I don't think that questions is very far off-topic, but it does seem rather discussion-y, and more than a little subjective and argumentative.  I wouldn't vote to reopen it.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise that - thanks.

Comment: How would I be able to get it re-opened though?

Comment: @Mantorok: Oh, seriously?  I thought any user could edit their own posts no matter what state they were in.  I'll set it to CW for you.  It already has 3 reopen votes, so it just needs 2 more.

Comment: @Mantorok: It requires that 5 people vote for reopening. When you have 250 rep you can vote for your own, when you have 3000 you can vote for all.

Comment: @Bill, sorry I typed that before checking! Yes you can change it to CW even when it's closed.

Comment: @Mantorok: Okay, thanks for clarifying that with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a question you own and convert it to community wiki by checking that very same box.

Marking something as CW doesn't necessarily mean that off topic questions won't get closed.  Your question requires extended discussion (read the FAQ), so it *is* off topic *and* subjective.  As ChrisF recommended in the comments, you would be better off supporting the [Not Programming Related proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) at Area 51.